# Calling similar sub routine names using a For Next or Do Loops

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is it possible to call similar sub routine names using a FOR NEXT or DO LOOPS.
I have forty sub routines with similar names. Each routine has minor variations.

I have tried using a CONTROL, example: `me.control("Sub Name", & I)`. Doesn't work.

Comment: *forty sub routines with similar names*...something tells me one sub can be used with passed in parameters. Keep your code DRY -Don't Repeat Yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to call a sub/function or a control event?

Inside your loop you can use:

`Call command1_click`

Or to call a sub/function just use the sub/function name and pass any variables required.

You should be careful not to have two subs/functions with the same name as you will run into trouble.

Edit: if calling a sub/function from outside the form, you should make sure it's public.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Application.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193559.aspx).

The called subs need to be in a standard module.

```
Sub Test1()
    Debug.Print "Test1"
End Sub

Sub Test2()
    Debug.Print "Test2"
End Sub

Sub TestIt()

    Dim S As String
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 2
        S = "Test" & i
        Application.Run S
    Next i

End Sub
```

Output of `TestIt`:

```
Test1
Test2
```

Answer (score 0):

you are right there you just need to change a couple things.  I just had to do this this morning I had controls day1 to day14 and for each dayi I was inputing values into excel.   What I did...

```
dim c as control
dim i as integer
for i = 1 to 40
set c = me.controls("sub name" & i)
'do whatever with the control here you use set to establish which control c is  
'then to set the value or use the value  
c = someexpression 'etc.

next
```